# Symfony2 Doctrine insert entity with related - NOT UPDATE

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have problem with inserting User entity with related entity UserProfile.

```
class User
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer",  options={"unsigned"=true})
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var UserProfile
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="UserProfile", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
protected $profile
....
}


class UserProfile
{
/**
 * @var User
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User",  inversedBy="profile" )
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $user;
.....
}
```

Standard User-UserProfile bidirectional relation. When I submit form contains fields from User entity and UserProfile entity,  $form->getData() gives me User object with UserProfile. So far so good.

Mysql generate a unique identity by auto-increment PK. To insert entity I have to do:

```
$em->persist($user)
$em->flush()
```

to get PK as id for persist and flush UserProfile.

But doctrine CANT insert $user because $user object has related $user->profile received from form Type:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
     ->add('email', 'email', array('label' => 'email'))
     ->add('profile', new RegistrationProfileFormType(), array('required'=>true,))
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'User',
        'cascade_validation'=>true,
    ));
}
```

**Update: Exception msg** 
Entity of type Entity\UserProfile has identity through a foreign entity Entity\User, however this entity has no identity itself. You have to call EntityManager#persist() on the related entity and make sure that an identifier was generated before trying to persist 'Entity\UserProfile'. In case of Post Insert ID Generation (such as MySQL Auto-Increment or PostgreSQL SERIAL) this means you have to call EntityManager#flush() between both persist operations.

Q: How to handle this problem properly ?

Sorry for my rusty English.

Comment: What exception message do you get when trying to submit your form?

Comment: Problem is how to clean object from related for first flush, when there is no PK/id for related. I did some dirty workaround but feel this is not right way. /**@PrePersist{

Comment: User Entity:    
/**@ORM\PrePersist*/ onPrePersist{ unset($this->profile)}, and inside controller $profile=$user->getProfile(); $em->persist($user);
$em->flush($user); $user->setProfile($profile);
$em->flush($user)

Comment: Sorry , I updated question - Exception msg.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are going to perist objects through not owning side. Owning side is the one with "inversedBy" property. And you should persist objects that way.

You can read more about it here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html

So, example for your case:

```
$profile->setUser($user);
$em->persist($profile).
$em->flush();
```

Although, if you want to keep the way you already have, there are two options:

1) Make `User` entity as the owning side and `UserProfile` as the inverse side

or

2) In your profile setter in `User` class do something like that:

```
public function setUserProfile(UserProfile $profile)
{
    $this->profile = $profile;
    $this->profile->setUser($this);
}
```

**edit:**

I've just notice that you don't have "id" field in your `UserProfile` entity - probably this is the reason. the easiest way would be separate primary and foreign keys. But if you want treat foreign as primary take a look at this article: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html#identity-through-foreign-entities

Comment: Hi. I want to keep mapping as is because that way I have UserProfile foreign key as User PK. That's not possible if I'll change owner side to User. Yes, I know about bidirectional update and I have setter set as you described. Doctrine cant insert UserProfile without id/PK and that is not possible without PK on User. Closed circle

Comment: Ok, so just add cascade={"persist"} to "user" mapping in your UserProfile, and that should help.

Comment: I had hoped this is it, but  still the same exception. :/

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I have Id. $user mapping  in UserProfile has that annotation. console doctrine:schem:create creates everything perfectly, including foreign constraint. I read that part Doctrine documentation you mention, I am using annotation and Use-Case 2: Simple Derived Identity - example looks exactly like my mapping.

Comment: Oh, ok, sorry I've missed that. So as the exception stays you can't do that in this way, because primary key of the inverse side depends on primary key of the owning side. So you can 1) reverse inversed-owning sides 2) separate primary key from foreign key in UserProfile (this would be my choice) 3) flush the owning side before inversed one. I can't see any other choice, but maybe it exists - I can't say